# how can i get last element iterator struts2

Tags: struts2, iterator

I'm looking for ideas to show only last element of iterator using struts 2

i have this code :

```
<s:iterator value="listuser"  status="userStatus">
<tr class="<s:if test="#userStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">
<td><s:property value="nameuser" /></td>
//  and others
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Why? Do this work in Java code.

Comment: I have this exemple show me all item exist in `value="listuser" ` and me i want just show the last element of this list

Comment: And I'm saying "don't do it in the view layer". You could access it via OGNL, e.g., `listuser.{$ #this instanceof User }` but IMO there are *several* reasons why this is a horrible idea.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what i should do?  if not exist in OGNL can  i get last element  by last  in veiw

Comment: You should get the last element in your action, not in the view layer. Or, as I said, abuse OGNL in the way I've shown. Although the code you posted implies you don't really want just the last item in the iterator.

Comment: @stoner You can always get the last element when an iterator completes.

Comment: @ Roman C how can i do it ? i have change in my query who fitch all element in list like this but not work  `session.createQuery("from user ORDER BY user_ID DESC LIMIT 1").list()`  now  i can give last by last

Comment: @stoner The query has wrong syntax and the iterator tag doesn't know what is the actual type of the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick :

```
<s:if test="#userStatus.index==listuser.size()-1">
           //Show the last element here
</s:if>
```

[UPDATE]

As per  Quaternion's comment, here's how to get it in one line :

```
 <s:set name="lastUser" value="listuser[listuser.size()-1]"/>
```

Above we set the last element in lastUser and here's how to use it else-where in the same page.

```
  <s:property value="#lastUser.name"/>
```

Comment: That is horrible, you just looped though all the values just for one?

Comment: To get the last element in one shot (should you use OGNL) it would be something like <s:set name="lastUser" value="listuser[listuser.size()-1]"/> UNTESTED

Comment: No problem for me because i use the some list in others place now it ok  thank you so much

Answer (score 11):

The [Struts2 Iterator Status](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) not only provide odd and even methods, it provides also a last and first method.

```
<s:iterator value="listuser"  status="userStatus">
  <s:if test="#userStatus.last == true ">
    <td><s:property value="nameuser" /></td>
  </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```